# path Issues through include with php

Tags: php, include, require

I want to have more structure in my project so I add some folders.
I had to change the includes / requires and found in google
this code
`$root = realpath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ); include "$root/some.php";` 
now i get an error

For example my project look like this:
[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ljfG.png)

if I am in test.php I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVr2l.png)

my index.php code:

```
<?php
var_dump("I'm in index.php");
echo  ' <a href="customer.php">Customer.php</a>' ; 
?>
```

my customer.php code:

```
<?php
var_dump("I'm in customer.php");
echo  ' <a href="php/functions/main/test.php">test.php</a>';
?>
```

my test.php code:

```
<?php
$root = realpath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] );
var_dump("I'm in test.php");
include "$root/index.php"
?>
```

or should I better use include "../../../index.php"; ?

thanks for your time

Comment: If you really want to save yourself a lot of trouble, looking into PHP routing. You create a single entry point for _all_ code, tell the server (Apache, angina, etc.) to route all (optionally non-existent) paths to the router. It then universally registers includes as needed, and then invokes your logic. This is pretty much how all modern frameworks work these days.